# Reporting progress of a org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job using a org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar

Tags: swt, jface, rcp

I would like to know whether it is possible and good practice to report the progress of a `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job` using a `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar`.

The javadoc says that the `run` method of `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job` takes a `org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor` argument. However I don't want to use a jface `ProgressMonitorDialog` and I'd rather a non-dialog widget.

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager`, which extends `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.ProgressProvider` to provide progress to Jobs.  You can provide a ProgressProvider, and that can return your preferred IProgressMonitor for use with Jobs.  You can base it on `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressIndicator` or work with ProgressBar directly.

As mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov in RCP you should use the IProgressSevice if possible, and you can display your progress in the ProgressView already provided in the workbench.

Answer (score 2):

In an RCP application, the best practice is to use [`IProgressService`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/progress/IProgressService.html).